# Result Code 22 Reported in Self-check: checkUpdate API Not Integrated

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I submitted my app to AppGallery Connect for self-check, the following message was displayed:
MAJOR:22: Integrate the version update API (checkUpdate). If you already integrate the API, check whether the HMS SDK code is obfuscated in the configuration file. For details about how to modify the configuration file, visit https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-preparation#h1-1574846682104.
Does anyone know what caused this?

Comment: This seems to be related [Result Code 22 Reported in Self-check: checkUpdate API Not Integrated](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/result-code-22-reported-in-self-check-checkupdate-api-not-integrated.4242693/)

Answer (score 0):

The checkUpdate API is required for joint operations games/apps if you have signed HUAWEI AppGallery Connect Distribution Service Agreement For Paid Apps. If you have not signed this agreement, please check whether corresponding resource files for the IAP SDK or DRM SDK have been introduced to your Game/App.. If so, the self-check tool will treat your app as a joint operations app, and prompt you to integrate this checkUpdate API. If no need to include this API, try to delete the related resources and perform the self-check again.

For details about how to integrate the API, please refer to:

[Joint operations games](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-game-update)

[Joint operations apps](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-update)